# Pipeline of functions scala

Tags: scala, f#, functional-programming

Is it possible to create a pipeline of functions in scala?. I wanted to do something like the following syntax in F#, achieved through the |> operator

```
indexPairs |> Seq.iter (fun (i,j) -> parents.[j] <- Some nodes.[i])
```

I know this can be easily done with a list comprehension, but the idea is to do more complex things like

```
indexPairs |> Seq.groupBy fst |> Seq.iter (fun (i, pairs) -> sons.[i] <- pairs |> Seq.map (fun (_,j) -> nodes.[j]) |> Seq.toList)
```

which helps to better readable code in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While using `Scalaz` as suggested in other answer for this is perfectly reasonable, you can add simple value class for the same purpose if you want to avoid adding external library dependency:

```
implicit class ChainOps[A](val value: A) extends AnyVal {
  def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(value)
}

def add(other: Int)(x: Int): Int = x + other
def mul(other: Int)(x: Int): Int = x * other
val value = 12
value |> add(9) |> mul(2) // 42
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use either `compose` or `andThen`.

```scala
val fComposeG = f _ compose g _ // fComposeG(x) equals f(g(x))
val fAndThenG = f _ andThen g _ // fAndThenG(x) equals g(f(x))
```

Comment: The `_` expansion (ETA) is not always required

Answer (score 2):

You can use from Scalaz the pipe operator in a syntax like this:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._

def f1(a:String):String =a + "1"
def f2(a:String):String =a + "2"
def f3(a:String):String =a + "3"
val text:String = "abc to xyz"
f1(text) |> f3 |> f2

scala> res2: String = abc to xyz132
```

Comment: I think it makes a little bit less sense in Scala. You can . into methods that are sort of overloaded. Also I'd avoid Scalaz like the plague, and if  `|>` is not a well accepted operator, then just don't use it. It's great in `F#`.